# Socket server in C stuck on call to function send() and not passing through it

Tags: c, sockets

I try to make a Socket client/server bundle running at the same time, passing information to one another. The problem is, after sending the first piece of data from the client, the server returns the answer correctly but becomes stuck on the call to function `send()`, disabling the ability for the server to receive another data from the client.

I use the following pieces of code in server and client:

### Client Code

```
char requestToSend[1000] = "Some request";
int client_socket;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
connect(client_socket, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

char buffer[MAX];
bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
send(server_socket, requestToSend, sizeof(requestToSend), 0);

bzero(requestToSend, sizeof(requestToSend));
while (strcmp(requestToSend, "") == 0) {
    recv(server_socket, requestToSend, sizeof(requestToSend), 0);
}

shutdown(client_socket, SHUT_RDWR);
printf("Received: %s", requestToSend); // requestToSend is not the received result!
```

### Server Code

The following code should return "My new result" in response to any request from the client.

```
while (1) {
    int server_socket, client_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_socket == -1) {
        printf("Socket creation failed...\n");
    } else {
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n");
    }
    bzero(&server, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if ((bind(server_socket, (SA*)&server, sizeof(server))) != 0) {
        printf("Socket binding failed...\n");
    } else {
        printf("Socket successfully bound..\n");
    }

    if ((listen(server_socket, 5)) != 0) {
        printf("Listen failed...\n");
    } else {
        printf("Server listening..\n");
    }

    socklen_t len = sizeof(client);
    client_socket = accept(server_socket, (SA*)&client, &len);
    if (client_socket < 0) {
        printf("Server accceptance failed...\n");
    } else {
        printf("Server acccepted the client..\n");
    }

    char buffer[MAX];
    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    recv(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    strcpy(buffer, "My new result");
    send(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    shutdown(server_socket, SHUT_RDWR);
}
```

There are other questions on Stack Overflow mentioning the problem of `send()` being stuck, but they don't provide an answer to this question.

Comment: I don't think that's where it's getting stuck. After it sends the reply it shuts down the client socket, then goes back to the beginning of the loop. It creates a new server socket and waits for another connection from the client. The `bind()` call should fail because the old server socket is still listening on the same port.

Comment: @Barmar You are right... I also receive "Socket binding failed". How can I manage to fix this problem and have a non-faulty connection between client and server?

Comment: You are not checking the return value of `send` and `recv`. If you are not interested in whether they succeed, you might just as well stop calling them. These functions return number of bytes sent and received. You **absolutely must** use the return values. There is no guarantee that the number of bytes you have asked to transfer is the number of bytes that will be transferred.

Answer (score 0):

You should only open and bind the server socket once. The loop should start before the `accept()` call. And you should close the client socket, not just call `shutdown()`.

When you're sending the reply, you should just send `strlen(buffer)+1` bytes, not `sizeof(buffer)`. The latter will send `MAX` bytes, which will include lots of uninitialized bytes. Adding 1 to `strlen()` will include the null byte.

```
int server_socket, client_socket;
struct sockaddr_in server, client;
server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (server_socket == -1) {
    printf("Socket creation failed...\n");
} else {
    printf("Socket successfully created..\n");
}
bzero(&server, sizeof(server));
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

if ((bind(server_socket, (SA*)&server, sizeof(server))) != 0) {
    printf("Socket binding failed...\n");
} else {
    printf("Socket successfully bound..\n");
}

if ((listen(server_socket, 5)) != 0) {
    printf("Listen failed...\n");
} else {
    printf("Server listening..\n");
}

while (1) {
    socklen_t len = sizeof(client);
    client_socket = accept(server_socket, (SA*)&client, &len);
    if (client_socket < 0) {
        printf("Server accceptance failed...\n");
    } else {
        printf("Server acccepted the client..\n");
    }

    char buffer[MAX];
    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    recv(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    strcpy(buffer, "My new result");
    send(client_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1, 0);
    close(client_socket);
}
```

The client's `recv()` loop should loop until it receives `0`, which indicates that the server has closed the socket. Each call should append to the buffer, not overwrite it.

```
char *ptr = requestToSend;
size_t len = sizeof(requestToSend);
int nread;
while ((nread = recv(server_socket, ptr, len, 0)) != 0) {
    if (nread < 0) {
        perror("recv from server");
        exit(1);
    }
    ptr += nread;
    len -= nread;
}
```

And it should also close the socket, not use `shutdown()`. `shutdown()` is generally only used when you want to half-close a socket -- you want to send EOF to the other system, but continue to read its responses.

Comment: When I run this provided code, the server code gets stuck in an infinite loop, printing "Server acceptance failed..." continuously.

Comment: I closed the wrong socket, sorry. It should be `close(client_socket)`.

Comment: I copied that from your code, you were shutting down the server socket, not the client socket.

Comment: Unfortunately now I have a new error printed on the client side and after that the app would quit: "recv from server: Connection reset by peer"

Comment: That should only happen if you try to send something to the server after it has closed the connection. I'm not sure why that would happen here, since the client only sends one message, and the server doesn't close until after it receives the message and sends the response.